# Visual Studio Code 1.25 with TypeScript 3.0 has gotten very slow

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

After the upgrade, I find that it takes a number of minutes to start to work. I see

`> Executing task: tsc --watch -p y:\dev\iis\Apps\fserve\server\tsconfig.json <`

and then nothing happens for ... five or more minutes. And still waiting for Intellisense to fully kick in.

Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have this problem with VSCode 1.25.1 and TS 3.0.1.  I think you'll probably need to give more details of your configuration or of the symptoms.  Sounds like a hard thing for someone else to reproduce 

Comment: I didn't make any change other than accept the update to 1.25 so it's hard to know the key factor. Trying it on another machine which needed TypeScript install but running VSC 1.7 so, if anything, it's a TS problem but still trying to isolate it as it's not start even after 15 minutes.

Comment: Will continue to work on it and am open to suggestions.

Comment: As an FYI I found a discussion at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32467. I also tested and more confused as it is not about TypeScript 3 nor VSC 1.25 per se.

Makes it even more mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the answer here [enter link description here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32467#issuecomment-413143244)

To save following the link:

**Solved**! It's a video server application and I had a subdirectory with junctions (links) to large libraries. Apparently, typescript searches in all the trees before it starts.

There isn't necessarily a fix as such but perhaps typescript could say what it's busy doing -- namely searching the file tree.

There is, however, a related bug in being unable to handle loops created in import (or worse). But that's part of the larger issue of very poor (OK, zilch) support for reparse points. This problem is exacerbated with OneDrive having its own approach with documentation I have yet to find.